# Using elements from a list with many levels to create a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
population = [[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1], [0]],
 [[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [3], [1]],
 [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [4], [2]],
 [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [3], [3]]]


def CreateDictionary(population):
   d=dict()
   for ind in range (0, len(population)):
       g = ','.join(str(ind[0][1]) for ind in population)
       f = ','.join(str(ind[1][1]) for ind in population)
   d[g] = f
   return (d)
```

The result I get is:

```
{'[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]': '[1],[3],[4],[3]'}
```

What I am trying to do is to create a dictionary using the first and second element for each part in the list (the third can be ignore) and assign one to the other, such as:

```
    d={'0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1': 1, 
'0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1': 3} and so on...
```

The first element (the binary sequence) can be text, it doesnt matter, but the second needs to be in a format that I can use to calculate other stuff. Since I am trying to do mathematical operations in this list form and its also not working.

I tried many things in other ways, but I get several errors while trying to run the code, this is the only way I could make it run but its not even close to what I wanted. Any thoughts on how I could approach this?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the point of storing keys like this? I can't see a dictionary being used as intended if this is how you're going to create it...

Comment: Do you _really_ want to use that data in string form as the key? Surely it would be better to use a tuple? Or convert that binary sequence to an int and use that as the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is what you want, use a `dictionary comprehension`. For converting the list to string, use the `join()` function after mapping each element to a string.

```
population = [[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1], [0]],
 [[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [3], [1]],
 [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [4], [2]],
 [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [3], [3]]]

d = {", ".join(map(str,i[0])):i[1][0] for i in population}
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0': 4, '1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0': 3, '0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1': 3, '0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1': 1}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, cant believe it was this simple

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution: We could convert the list to numbers base 10 (from binary):

```
def return_decimal(lst):
    return int(''.join(map(str,lst)),2)

population = [[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1], [0]],
 [[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [3], [1]],
 [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [4], [2]],
 [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [3], [3]]]

d = dict((return_decimal(i[0]),i[1][0]) for i in population)
```

Returns:

```
{40152: 3, 11745: 1, 27876: 4, 14769: 3}
```

To find a value:

```
find = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1] # 11745

d.get(return_decimal(find))
```

Returns:

```
1
```

Comment: I like this answer - converting to decimal int is a smart move.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really see a use for a `dict` created like this (indexing becomes a pain). I'd really suggest just keeping separate lists `x` and `y` (see my answer). But you can create a `dict` by passing tuples of `x` and `y` to the `dict` constructor:

```
x, y, *_ = zip(*population)

x = [', '.join(map(str, z)) for z in x]
y = [z[0] for z in y]
```

---

```
d = dict(zip(x, y))

d
{'0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1': 1,
 '0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1': 3,
 '0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0': 4,
 '1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0': 3}
```

Comment: I was trying to perform calculations with the fitness values (values assigned to the binary sequences) and it was alo a pain, I guess I am creating that only to calculate the probabilities proportion and adding the results to a second list, that I can index later in the same positions as the "population", do you think its a good idea?

Comment: @vferraz If you are indexing by position, you _absolutely_ need a list. See `x`, and `y` in my answer - they are enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could try dict comprehension :

```
population_dict = {" ".join(str(x) for x in item[0]): int(item[1][0]) for item in population}
```

this dict comprehension is same as:

```
population_dict={}

for item in population:
    population_dict[" ".join(str(x) for x in item[0])] = int(item[1][0])

print(population_dict)
```

output:

```
{'0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1': 3, '0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1': 1, '1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0': 3, '0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0': 4}
```